# Restore default /etc directory

Tags: fedora, etc

I just ran a script I'm working on, and due to a mistake in directories, overwrote most of the default `/etc` directory files.

I can re-add my user account easily, but most other things are gone such as:

```
fstab
passwd
group
issue
mtab (syn link)
mdev
profile
inittab
shells
release
hostname
hosts
```

I'm not using any real custom configs, mostly a base `Fedora 19` install upgraded last week to `Fedora 20` via `fedup`.

Do I have any options to re-create the default `/etc` files including my default-from-install `fstab`?

I haven't shutdown/rebooted since this happened... so my current session is still active, although I can't open any additional terminals without getting the `I have no name!` user showing up (with no correct env variables); I do have one valid terminal open (if there is some way to write-out it's env variables or something).

Reinstalling is possible as a last resort.

Comment: Perhaps try extundelete ? http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I suspect that a reinstall is the only way to have any confidence in the system again. Another possibility is to perform a fresh install onto another server/VM, and either transfer the files, or copy and paste each one. It depends on whether utilities such as `scp` are still working for you though.

Comment: @Warwick ya, i'm going to resort to a reinstall this evening. It's a development laptop so nothing major... more of a PITA than anything. -- the entire thing was caused by a path being wrongly prefixed by `/` when it should have used the working directory as it's root instead... damn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Warwick -- A clean install is the only sane option at this point. Rebuilding the `fstab` in particular would be challenging since Fedora uses `UUID`'s for mappings.

Time to backup any data, then re-install.